Understanding the Meaning of “No Thing”
In the lyric “It wasn’t no thing to give you up,” should it be understood as “It wasn’t difficult to give you up” or “It wasn’t easy to give you up”? I’m confused about the meaning of “no thing” here.
Further, does 'no thing' equal to 'nothing'?
(Morgan Wallen -- Lies Lies Lies)

Google asks me whether I meant 'It wasn't nothing…'
Can you Post link to the lyrics you really mean?

“Ain’t no thing” (or “ain’t no thang”) is a fixed expression meaning “[it] is of no importance”.  This answer claims it started life as “ain’t no thing but a chicken wing”.
Perhaps Mr Wallen changed “ain’t” to “wasn’t” for euphony or scansion.  Maybe he just thought it was “proper English”.

You should point out that the saying is US rural/regional dialect.

Seems to be a double negative, common in many dialects of English. And "wasn't" is past tense of "ain't" (which is simple present tense).

@MichaelHarvey — it is not rural or regional.  Songwriter Morgan Wallen (born in Sneedville, Tennessee) might be rural or regional but the expression comes from BVE.

I don't think it originates in BVE but in southern speech. Compare: "it warn't nothing new to me , and I suppose to you nother"  in Letters of J. Downing, Major. Downingville Militia, Second Brigade, to his old friend, Mr. Dwight, of the New-York Daily Advertiser ed. Charles Augustus Davis (New York, 1836)

https://www.google.com/books/edition/Letters_of_J_Downing_Major_Downingville/TJ9V0i8eEqIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22It+warn%27t+no+thing%22&pg=PA321&printsec=frontcover

@TimR — “it is nothing new” (like “it is nothing important” and “it is nothing at all” and just “it is nothing”) is very common in all English dialects; the double-negative is reasonably common in regional and casual speech.  My sense is that “ain’t no thing” came not from there but from “no big thing” (and other adjectives), where the adjective gradually got elided.
